# Message not sending in a channel discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

For some reason i cant seem to get this to work tried everything i could to fix it for somereason Channel.send is not a function when i made it one near the top if anyone can help me with this please let me know!

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
    name: 'report',
    usage: '%report <reason>',
    description: 'reports a person',

    async execute(client, message, args) {
        let user = message.mentions.users.first() || await message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0])

        if (!user) return message.reply(`Please mention a user to report`)

        let reason = args.slice(1).join(" ")
        if (!reason) return message.reply(`Please enter a reason`)

        let Avatar = user.displayAvatarURL();
        let Channel = message.guild.channels.cache.find((ch) => ch.name === "reports")
        if (!Channel) return message.reply(`Thier is no Valid channel to send a report please contact a staff member`)

        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle('New Report')
            .setDescription(`The member ${message.author.tag} has reported ${user.tag}`)
            .setColor("RED")
            .setThumbnail(Avatar)
            .addFields({ name: "Member ID,", value: `${message.author.id}`, inline: true }, { name: "Member Tag,", value: `${message.author.tag}`, inline: true }, { name: "Reported ID,", value: `${user.id}`, inline: true }, { name: "Reported Tag,", value: `${user.tag}`, inline: true }, { name: "Reason,", value: `${reason}`, inline: true })
        Channel.send(embed)
        message.channel.send(`Successfully sent the report!`)
    }
}
```

Heres the error as well

```js
PS C:\Users\lolzy\OneDrive\Desktop\discordbot> node .
Cbs slave is online!
(node:8056) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Channel.send is not a function
    at Object.execute (C:\Users\lolzy\OneDrive\Desktop\discordbot\commands\report.js:26:17)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\lolzy\OneDrive\Desktop\discordbot\events\guild\message.js:10:26)
    at Client.emit (events.js:376:20)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\lolzy\OneDrive\Desktop\discordbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\lolzy\OneDrive\Desktop\discordbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\lolzy\OneDrive\Desktop\discordbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\lolzy\OneDrive\Desktop\discordbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\lolzy\OneDrive\Desktop\discordbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\lolzy\OneDrive\Desktop\discordbot\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:132:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:376:20)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:8056) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:8056) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your channel is not defined correctly. I would advise you using this instead:

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
    name: 'report',
    usage: '%report <reason>',
    description: 'reports a person',

    async execute(client, message, args) {
        let user = message.mentions.users.first() || await message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0])

        if (!user) return message.reply(`Please mention a user to report`)

        let reason = args.slice(1).join(" ")
        if (!reason) return message.reply(`Please enter a reason`)

        let Avatar = user.displayAvatarURL();
        let Channel = findChannel(client, "reports")
        if (!Channel) return message.reply(`Thier is no Valid channel to send a report please contact a staff member`)

        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle('New Report')
            .setDescription(`The member ${message.author.tag} has reported ${user.tag}`)
            .setColor("RED")
            .setThumbnail(Avatar)
            .addFields({
                name: "Member ID,",
                value: `${message.author.id}`,
                inline: true
            }, {
                name: "Member Tag,",
                value: `${message.author.tag}`,
                inline: true
            }, {
                name: "Reported ID,",
                value: `${user.id}`,
                inline: true
            }, {
                name: "Reported Tag,",
                value: `${user.tag}`,
                inline: true
            }, {
                name: "Reason,",
                value: `${reason}`,
                inline: true
            })



        client.channels.cache.get(Channel).send(embed);
        message.channel.send(`Successfully sent the report!`)
    }
}




//This function returns the channelID of the channel with the parsed name
//NOTE: make sure no category has the name, otherwise some extra checks would have to be made
function findChannel(client, channelName) {
    var channelId = client.channels.cache.find(c => c.name.toLowerCase().includes(channelName.toLowerCase())).id;
}
```

Let me know if that fixed your Problem

Comment: It did not fix it sadly but i got this error upon testing sorry im a bit new to this

Comment: PS C:\Users\lolzy\OneDrive\Desktop\discordbot> node .
Cbs slave is online!
(node:4720) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: client is not defined

Comment: Sorry, I fixed the problem. It should work now

Comment: its good but i got a nother error

PS C:\Users\lolzy\OneDrive\Desktop\discordbot> node .
Cbs slave is online!
(node:13880) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'cache' of undefined

Comment: Alright, had a typo in channel`s`. It should now finally work!

Comment: PS C:\Users\lolzy\OneDrive\Desktop\discordbot> node .
Cbs slave is online!
(node:16184) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: c.toLowerCase is not a function

Comment: we will get thier someday

Comment: My bad. You have to lowercase the name of course. So Yeah, now it should work. Fingers crossed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234038/discussion-between-cb12438-and-christoph-blum).